# Design a divide and conquer algorithm to find the real card

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I am thinking about a D&S problem to find the real card in a group of cards. The real cards all have the same code and the fake cards have many codes(can be same or not). The number of real cards is bigger than half.  I can only compare two cards to see if they have the same code but cannot determine what the code is.

What I am thinking about now is to divide the group into smaller group recursively. Then, I put the cards with the same code to a set. Finally, I just need to find the largest set, the element will be the real card. But I don't really know how to achieve it.

Comment: Sounds like [Boyer-Moore majority vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer–Moore_majority_vote_algorithm). I don't see a need for D&C.

Comment: @user58697 but the D&C is requirement

Comment: Here is a hint:  If you break the input into two halves, at least one half will still contain the majority element.  So if you solve the majority element problem on both halves, you then have at most two candidates.

Comment: @RobNeuhaus Here is an optimization.  You first process one half then see if its answer works across the whole.  If you're clever and only moderately lucky you'll quickly identify the majority element, and then only need to run enough comparisons to verify that it is the majority.

Comment: Yeah, I think that turns it from O(n log n) to O(n) in expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify quicksort for your purposes.

Pick a random element to be a pivot, find the 3 buckets of less, equal or greater.  If more than half are equal, you're done.  Otherwise throw away everything but the biggest bucket and repeat.

Average case will be `O(n)`.  Worst case is `O(n^2)`.  If needed you can improve the worst case with the usual median of medians algorithm that exists for quicksort.

Comment: This presumes the set is well-ordered -- that there is also a "less than" relation between any two elements.  Your rationale works, but I think the only partition we get is "equal" vs "not equal".